# Why does a non-prime DH modulus creates a "NOBUS" backdoor

Tags: diffie-hellman, backdoors

can't we do a nobus backdoor with DH modulus prime? Some have argued that with a prime modulus you can just get the order by doing p-1 and then factor it, thus it is easy to reverse. I argue that this is not true.

### The prime case

Our modulus is a prime $p$ such that the order of the group is $p-1 = p_1^{k_1} \times \cdots \times p_n^{k_n}$

For the backdoor to work, the discrete log should be do-able in groups of order $p_i^{k_i}$

For the NOBUS to work, you shouldn't be able to find the factors $p_i^{k_i}$

### The non-prime case

Our modulus is now a composite $n = p_1^{k_1} \times \cdots \times p_n^{k_n}$ such that the order of the group is $p_1^{k_1-1}(p_1-1) \times \cdots \times p_n^{k_n-1}(p_n -1)$

For the backdoor to work, the discrete log should be do-able in groups of order $p_i^{k_i-1}(p_i-1)$

For the NOBUS to work, you shouldn't be able to find the factors $p_i^{k_i}$

### The difference?

I see almost no difference between these two problems. It seems like a NOBUS backdoor could as easily be created with a prime modulus as with non-prime one.

Thoughts?

Comment: "do-able in" ​ -> ​ "do-able in groups of order" ​ ​ ​ ? ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: yes this is right

Comment: While not relevant to the question (difference between prime and non-prime moduli), please note that it is possible to prove numbers to be prime and to quickly find out that a number is composite. So such a modulus would cast suspicion really quickly.

Comment: This is what happened with socat (https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11014175)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [In the non-prime case] For the backdoor to work, the discrete log should be do-able in $p_i^{k_i-1}(p_i - 1)$

Actually, that's not quite correct, and that's relevant for the answer.

If the factorization of $p_i^{k_i-1}(p_i - 1)$ is $p_i^{k_i-1} q_1^a q_2^b ... q_n^z$, then for NOBUS to work, someone else shouldn't be able to find the factors $q_i$.

Here's why this distinction is important: in the prime case, everyone knows the size of the group $p-1$, and anyone can hand off that value to a factoring method that's good at finding small factors, such as [Elliptic Curve Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic_curve_factorization).  That is an astoundingly good way for find small factors, and for ECM, small can be 128 bits...

So, if $p-1$ consists of factors that are small enough for us to use, ECM can find them without much difficulty.

However, if we use a composite modulus, the size of the group is now secret. In other words, we've shifted the problem to finding the $q_i$ values.  Here, ECM doesn't help us much; unlike the prime case, there isn't a convenient $p-1$ value we can hand to ECM.  And, by making the $p_1, p_2$ values comparatively large, ECM just doesn't work the modulus directly.

What would work (to some extent) is the $p-1$ factoring method.  There, we keep making guesses as to the various primes that make up $q_i$; if we guess all of them on one side (and there's no penalty, apart from wasting time, for incorrect guesses), then we factor.  So, if we have a 64 bit $q_i$ value (and assuming the attacker knows that), he can guess all 64 bit primes; however there's about $2^{58}$ of them, so it'll take a while...

Comment: right, I missed the fact that in the non-prime case. The DLOG doesn't have to be "do-able" in $p_i - 1$ if $p_i - 1$ is smooth. So in the non-prime case you can use $p_i$ that are much larger than in the prime case

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, in both cases an attacker has to factor the group order and compute logarithms in small subgroups, but in the non-prime case there is an additional step: **factoring the modulus**.

The standard [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm) for computing logarithms in [smooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number)-order groups requires a factorization of the group order. Of course, If those factors are "small", anyone can compute such a factorization **given the group order**. This is where the difference lies:

- For prime moduli $p$, the group order is just $p-1$, which anyone can trivially compute.
- But suppose the modulus $n$ is a product of two **large** primes $p$ and $q$ such that $p-1$ and $q-1$ are smooth: Then the group order is $\lvert(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^\ast\rvert=\varphi(n)=(p-1)(q-1)$, which is also smooth, but computing $\varphi(n)$ without knowledge of $p$ or $q$ is generally [hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_problem). Notice the difference between factoring the group order (which is easy in both cases since it is smooth) and factoring the *modulus* (which is trivial in the prime case but can be very hard in the composite case). Therefore **"anyone but us" cannot obtain the group order** while "we" (having generated $p$ and $q$) of course can.

Comment: "but in the non-prime case there is an additional step: factoring the modulus", well you have to factor the order in the prime case

Comment: what I'm saying in my post is that factoring the modulus in the non-prime case is equivalent to factoring the order in the prime case.

Comment: ahh... I completely missed the fact that p_i-1 is smooth in the non-prime case, so the factors p_i can be way bigger