# RSA How to find the exponent ($e$) of the Public key with the values $p$ $q$ and an example are given

Tags: rsa, public-key

I'm wondering if it's possible to find the public exponent ($e$) with an example and the (rather small) values of $p$ and $q$ given.

Currently the only option I found is bruteforcing this value, but this can be very slow for a large $e$.

And if there is no perfect technique, is there a way to limit the amount of options significantly?

**Is it possible to find $e$ with $p$, $q$ and an example encrypted message + answer given?**

Comment: There's [an old answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/807/29407) that says discrete log in the composite modulus case is as difficult as it is in the prime case, so probably not. You can at least precompute all the powers of 2 modulii of your message and then just test combinations of them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does a non-prime DH modulus creates a "NOBUS" backdoor](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/32522/why-does-a-non-prime-dh-modulus-creates-a-nobus-backdoor)

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage As the question is explicitly about RSA you should at least indicate why you think this duplicates the other question, please.

Comment: The question is how to compute a discrete log (find $e$ given $x^e$) modulo a composite ($pq$).